# Cloud Firestore java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type:

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am adding document to a collection in Cloud Firestore of the Firebase and keep getting this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: com.example.com.myproject.PickUpDate (found in field pick_up)

I store the object in a following way:

```
private fun storeData() {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val offerDocument = HashMap<String, Any?>()
    offerDocument.put(Key.CATEGORY, offer.category)
    offerDocument.put(Key.ITEM_TYPE, offer.itemType)
    offerDocument.put(Key.BRAND, offer.brand)
    offerDocument.put(Key.PRICE, offer.price)
    offerDocument.put(Key.PICK_UP_DATE, offer.pickUpPickUpDate)
    offerDocument.put(Key.AVAILABILITY, offer.availability)
    offerDocument.put(Key.COLOR, offer.color)

   offer.images =  adapter?.list?.map { it.toString() }
    offerDocument.put(Key.IMAGES, offer.images)


    // Add a new document with a generated ID
    db.collection("offers")
            .add(offerDocument)
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference -> Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.id) }
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e) }
}
```

And my PickUpDate class is following:

```
data class PickUpDate(var year : Int, var month : Int, var day : Int){}
```

What could be the reason? Why the exception is thrown specifically on this class not others?

Comment: Do you have an example of the other classes that don't have any errors?

Comment: @cricket_007 look the category class : data class Category(var name: String, var id: Int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing the types of all the other fields that you're adding to the map to put in the document.  My guess is that they're all primitive types, such as integers or strings.  PickUpDate is a custom class you've defined, rather than one of the standard types supported for document fields in Firestore.

If you want to create an field in a document that contains an object with the three values contained within PickUpDate, you could put them in a HashMap, then assign that HashMap to a field in the document:

```
val map = mapOf<String, Any>(
    "year" to offer.pickUpPickUpDate.year,
    "month" to offer.pickUpPickUpDate.month,
    "day" to offer.pickUpPickUpDate.day
)

offerDocument.put(Key.PICK_UP_DATE, map)
```

Or, find some other way to encode the values in your object into a valid field value (like a timestamp, or a single number).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: com.example.com.myproject.PickUpDate

Because in Firestore you cannot assign to your `PICK_UP_DATE` property, a value that is not a 
[supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). Your `PickUpDate` class is not a suported one. To solve this, you need to change the type of that property to one of those that are supported.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Thank you very much, I've put the objects of custom types in a map as @Doug Stevenson suggested. Of course it isn't that nice, but we have to follow the rules and put only supported types